# What option do I set for a SQL Server connection pool to use Azure Active Directory authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-mysql-database

Trying to connect to a SQL Server database on Azure and use Azure Active Directory instead of using the default SQL authentication. Current options w/ my idea of using set domain but not sure what it'd be:

```
    this.config = {
            server: dbConnectionInfo.server,
            port: dbConnectionInfo.port,
            database: dbConnectionInfo.database,
            user: dbConnectionInfo.user,
            password: dbConnectionInfo.password,
            // domain: dbConnectionInfo.domain, set domain?
            options: {
                trustServerCertificate: true,
                encrypt: true,
                useUTC: false
            },
        };

    this.connectionPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(this.config);
    this.connectionPoolPromise = this.connectionPool.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace user and password with auth and options:

```
this.config = {
    server: dbConnectionInfo.server,
    port: dbConnectionInfo.port,
    database: dbConnectionInfo.database,
    authentication: {
        type: "azure-active-directory-msi-app-service",
        options: {
            tenantId: "tenant_id",  // your AAD tenant ID
            clientId: "client_id,  // your AAD client ID
        },
    },
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        encrypt: true,
        useUTC: false,
    },
};
```

But you did not specify what type of AAD you have so I cannot be for sure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#setting-azure-active-directory-authentication

Comment: Thank you but it uses a username and password still so I don't believe it's that.

Comment: azure-active-directory

Comment: so you want the first one from the list, Active Directory Password. I will change my answer according to that

Comment: that'd be great